# Removing Brackets and Quotes in Output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a couple of functions that I'm working with and I've tried using `.split()` to remove the brackets, but the brackets and quotes still show in the output. I have the functions separate because I plan on calling `fn_run_cmd` within many different functions.

```
def fn_run_cmd(*args):
    cmd = ['raidcom {} -s {} -I{}'.format(list(args),
           storage_id, horcm_num)]
    print(cmd)

def fn_find_lun(ldev, port, gid):
    result = fn_run_raidcom('get lun -port {}-{}'.format(port, gid))
    return(result)
    match = re.search(r'^{} +{} +\S+ +(?P<lun>\d+) +1 +{} '.format(
                  port, gid, ldev), result[1], re.M)
    if match:
        return(match.group('lun'))
    return None
```

Below is the output I'm getting:

```
"raidcom ['get lun -port CL1-A-2'] -s [987654] -I[99]"
```

Desired result:

```
raidcom get lun -port CL1-A-2 -s 987654 -I99
```

Comment: have you tried using the string.replace() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `cmd` become a list, change it to become a string by unwrapping surrounding `[.....]`

```
cmd = 'raidcom {} -s {} -I{}'.format(list(args),
      storage_id, horcm_num)
```

`list(args)`, `storage_id`, `horcm_num` are list. They need to be passed as arguments of strings, not lists; Use `func(*...)` to expand list into argument:

```
def fn_run_cmd(*args):
    cmd = 'raidcom {} -s {} -I{}'.format(*list(args) + storage_id + horcm_num)
    print(cmd)
```